# Apache: How redirect from domain.com to www.domain.com

Tags: apache

Apache: How redirect from domain.com to www.domain.com?

I dont want my users who type domain w/o www to be redicrect to the main www.domain

how to do it and where? local .htaccess or the apache config (I have Ubuntu server)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

More info: http://enarion.net/web/htaccess/redirect-www-and-no-www/